# Accessing django database from python script

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to access my Django database from within a regular Python script. So far what I did is:

```
import os
import django
from django.db import models

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "m_site.settings")
django.setup()

from django.apps import apps
ap=apps.get_model('py','Post')

q=ap.objects.all()

for a in q:
    print(a.title)
```

There is an application in Django called `py` where I have many posts (`models.py`, which contains `class Post(models.Model)`).

I would like to have the possibility to access and update this database from a regular Python script. So far script above works fine, I can insert, update or query but it looks like it is a separate database and not the database from Django's `py` application. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The code above should use the `DATABASES` configuration from your `m_site.settings` module.

Comment: Do you know how to properly read databases configuration from django and then get objects from specified app ?

Comment: The code you have shown should access the database defined in `DATABASES` in `m_site.settings`. You don't have to read the configuration manually, so asking "how to properly read databases configuration" doesn't really make sense. We can't really help any further, because you haven't said what `DATABASES` in `m_site.settings` is, or which database you wish to connect to.

Comment: Sure, I,ve forgot to say it is default db:  DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: It sounds like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')` doesn't point to the correct sqlite file.

Comment: Thanks for help @Alasdair but now i'm working with commands. Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider writing your script as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/). This will let you run it via `manage.py`, with Django all properly wired up for you, e.g.

```
python manage.py print_post_titles
```

Something like this should be a good start:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from py.models import Post

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Prints the titles of all Posts'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for post in Post.objects.all():
            print(a.title)
```